Understanding 世間が先生を知らないで平気でいる
From Kokoro chapter 11:

先生はまるで世間に名前を知られていない人であった。だから先生の学問や思想については、先生と密切の関係をもっている私より外に敬意を払うもののあるべきはずがなかった。それを私は常に惜しい事だといった。先生はまた「私のようなものが世の中へ出て、口を利いては済まない」と答えるぎりで、取り合わなかった。私にはその答えが謙遜過ぎてかえって世間を冷評するようにも聞こえた。実際先生は時々昔の同級生で今著名になっている誰彼を捉えて、ひどく無遠慮な批評を加える事があった。それで私は露骨にその矛盾を挙げて云々してみた。私の精神は反抗の意味というよりも、世間が先生を知らないで平気でいるのが残念だったからである。その時先生は沈んだ調子で、「どうしても私は世間に向かって働き掛ける資格のない男だから仕方がありません」といった。先生の顔には深い一種の表情がありありと刻まれた。私にはそれが失望だか、不平だか、悲哀だか、解らなかったけれども、何しろ二の句の継げないほどに強いものだったので、私はそれぎり何もいう勇気が出なかった。

I am bit uncertain who is the subject for 平気でいる. I initially understood 世間が先生を知らないで平気でいる as "the world remains at peace without knowing Sensei" but I wonder if there's a possibility that Sensei is the subject for 平気でいる. If that's case, then it would be understood as "Sensei is okay with the world not knowing him"?

Nothing indicates the implicit change of subjects, so I think your initial interpretation is correct. The subject of 平気でいる is simply 世間. If your second interpretation had been intended, the sentence would have been 先生が世間に知られずに平気でいる.
